# Solving Ultrahyperbolic Equation (4D) With NDSolveValue

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

So we were trying to solve the Ultrahyperbolic Equation with two spatial dimensions and two time dimensions in Mathematica using NDSolveValue.

[image: Formulation of Ultrahyperbolic Equation]

We understand that the problem, in general, is not solvable (ill-posed) if a proper boundary condition/initial condition is not provided. One possible condition to impose on this problem to obtain a unique (well-posed) solution is mentioned in https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/004155539090035Q?via%3Dihub is that

[image]

So I tried to implement this in Mathematica,

[image]

```
G = ImplicitRegion[
   x^2 + y^2 - s^2 <= 
    t^2, {{x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, {t, 0, 5}, {s, 0, 5}}];
H = ImplicitRegion[
   t^2 + s^2 == 
    x^2 + y^2, {{x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, {t, 0, 5}, {s, 0, 5}}];
uifWave2 = NDSolveValue[{\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \(t, t\)]\(w[x, y, t, s]\)\) + \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \(s, s\)]\(w[x, y, t, s]\)\) - \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \(x, x\)]\(w[x, y, t, s]\)\) - \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \(y, y\)]\(w[x, y, t, s]\)\) == 0,
       DirichletCondition[w[x, y, t, s] == s^2, 
    s^2 + t^2 == x^2 + y^2 && 0 <= s <= 5 && 0 <= t <= 5 && 
     0 <= x <= 5 && 0 <= y <= 5 (*{x,y,t,s}∈ H *) ]}, 
      w, {x, y, t, s} ∈ G ] 
FullSimplify[uifWave2]
(*Imposing the derivative condition*)
```

But I get an error, and the following stack and trace info:
[image]

It seems that Mathematica is unable to resolve the "Implict Region" command. My hunch is that the NDsolve does not quite work with constrained region in 4D. **Is there any work-around on this?**

(Note: The one dimensional time (2 spatial dim) case seems to work just fine.)
[image]

Comment: People will be less likely to help you if you do not provide code that others can easily copy and paste. Don't force potential helpers to retype code you've already typed.

Comment: Most likely the max dim is 3. Try for instance `ToElementMesh[G]`; pay attention to the message name (even though the message text is undefined).